# Получить часы и минуты

Tags: javascript

Есть строка "09:15:00".
Как получить значения 09 и 15?

Comment: Есть `split` для подобных случаев

Comment: [tag:jquery] - серьёзно?

Comment: @Qwertiy многие стали считать что это отдельный язык программирования :) Нечему удивляться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `split(s)` - позволяет превратить строку в массив, разбив ее по разделителю `s`.

Например

```js
var names = 'Маша, Петя, Марина, Василий';
var arr = names.split(', ');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  alert( 'Вам сообщение ' + arr[i] );
}
```

Выведет:

```
Вам сообщение Маша
Вам сообщение Петя
Вам сообщение Марина
Вам сообщение Василий
```

В Вашем случае разделителем будет двоеточие:

```js
var d = "09:15:00"; 

var splitted = d.split(':');
document.write('Первое значение: ' + splitted[0] + ', Второе значение: ' + splitted[1]);
```

Подробнее о методе `split` можно прочитать [Здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods)

Answer (score 2):

2 варианта решения

```js
var str = '09:15:00';
var arr = str.split(':');
var strSplitHours = arr[0];
var strSplitMinutes = arr[1];
document.write('вариант1 - Часы:'+strSplitHours+' Минуты:'+strSplitMinutes+'<br>');

var regexHours = str.replace(/(\d\d).*/,'$1');
var regexMinutes = str.replace(/\d\d.(\d\d).*/,'$1');

document.write('вариант2 - Часы:'+regexHours+' Минуты:'+regexMinutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Я всё-таки придумал, как выпендриться и использовать jQuery :)
Ну и по пути применил ES6.

В 49м хроме работает.

```js
for (let str of ["09:15:00", "09:15:02", "00:15:00", "09:00:47"]) {
  const date = $("<input type=time step=1>").val(str)[0].valueAsDate;

  $("body").append($("<p>").text(
    "{{getUTCHours| h}} {{getUTCMinutes| min}} {{getUTCSeconds| sec}}"
    .replace(/\{\{(\w+)\|(.*?)\}\}/g, (s, m, t) => (m=date[m]()) ? m+t : "")
  ));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: замените тогда `var` на `let`.)

Comment: @betonimig, ещё и на const заменил)

Comment: в `for` тоже можно `let` на `const` поменять)

Comment: @betonimig, разные интереснее.

Answer (score 1):

И вот так вот простенько можно, чтобы вообще не заморачиваться =)

```js
var foo = "09:15:00";
document.write('часы: ' + foo[0]+foo[1] + ' ; минуты: ' + foo[3]+foo[4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант с помощью [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var str = '09:15:00';
var names = ["Часы", "Минуты", "Секунды"];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(str.match(/\d+/g).map(function(el, i) {
  return {
    [names[i]]: el
  };
}), null, 2) + '</pre>');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(str.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function(acc, el, i) {
  acc[names[i]] = el;
  return acc;
}, {}), null, 2) + '</pre>');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(str.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function(acc, el, i) {
  return Object.assign(acc, {
    [names[i]]: el
  });
}, {}), null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Что ж не в один объект? Давай reduce'ом добьём?

Comment: @Qwertiy, зачем?:) это ж разные элементы :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил вариант с reduce :-)

Comment: Кстати, у тебя тоже ES6 из-за вычисляемых свойств :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, только в мапе - в редусе - старый добрый ES5 :)

Comment: Ага, забавно звучит :) Кстати, тебе группа не нужна - она всё равно не используется.

Comment: ага, я знаю, наверное когда с теста копировал забыл убрать

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил еще вариант с reduce когда только return в функции

Answer (score 1):

Обычный match например

```js
var s = '09:15:00';
var r = s.match(/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/);
var h = r[1];
var m = r[2];
var s = r[3];
console.log(h, m, s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю в копилку вариант с ES6 (без транспайлинга почти нигде не заработает):

```
let [hours, minutes] = "09:15:00".split(':').map(Number)
```

`.map(Number)` можно добавить, если нужно получить именно числовое значение. Если нужно строку - убрать.

Answer (score 0):

### Проблема решается стандартными методами JS:

```js
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 09:15:00");
d.getMinutes();
d.getHours();

console.log(d.getMinutes(), d.getHours());
```

Comment: не любую строку можно передать в конструктор