# Как из строки вытащить число на javascript

Tags: javascript, строки

Как из строки такого вида "20:153" "1568:23" вытащить число после двоеточия?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить часы и минуты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515212/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3):

```
let res = "1568:23".split(":")[1];
```

Comment: @Valeriy Petukhov обозначь ответ как правильный, спасибо.